# How to use a static property from an abstract sealed class (C++/CLI)

Tags: dll, c++-cli, clr, abstract, sealed

I'm trying to work with a .NET DLL. When I create a new CLR project and add the DLL reference I have a class that shows up as `public : ref class <name> abstract sealed`. The class has two properties both defined as `public : static property`.

I can't figure out how to use them. Anything I try results with a compiler error (fatal error C1001). For instance I specify the namespace and the class separated by two colons and terminate it with a semicolon, for example `class::property;` does not give me the `System::String` variable. Normally this is fine in C++  but creates a compiler error with CLR.

I've tried both Visual Studio 2015 and 2013 and I get the same error. Any help on how to use this DLL is appreciated.

There are some samples on how to use the SDK with C# but not with CLR.

**Some more information:**

The SDK is actually a label design software called Nicelabel and the DLL is called SDK.Net.interface and is part of the Powerforms Suite install.
When I do something simple like the statement below I get the C1001 error:

> NiceLabel::SDK::PrintEngineFactory::SDKFilesPath = "c:\\Temp";

Comment: public : static property System::String^ SDKFilesPath { get; set; }
   Member of NiceLabel::SDK::PrintEngineFactory

Comment: public : ref class PrintEngineFactory abstract sealed
    Member of NiceLabel::SDK

Comment: MyForm.cpp(24): note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'NiceLabel::SDK::PrintEngineFactory ' from assembly 'SDK.NET.Interface, Version=17.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=865eaf3445b2ea56'.

Comment: The problem is I cannot recreate this with example code. It all seems to work fine when I create code in my project. I will create a new DLL and see if I have the same problem when referencing this.

Comment: The code you are trying to use looks okay.  But C1001 is a very nasty error, the compiler crashed.  What destabilized it so badly is not obvious from the question at all.  Try using it from a C# project and on another machine to gather more evidence.

Comment: Well everything I tried has worked so far, I create a C# class library (VS2013 and VS2015) and then reference it in my app without any problems. Maybe the DLL was created with VB instead and this doesn't work with CLI/C++? Not sure how to implement a static class in VB though for testing.